# Going to next loop iteration, unexpectedly changes the values

Tags: c++

On my class header I have:

```
struct Block {
    // ...
}

private:
    Block *m_root;
```

My class implementation contains:

```
for (Block block : blocks) {
    // ...
}
```

Stepping through the code in debugger, I observe:

Exactly at the **end of 1st iteration** of loop, my private member `m_root` is:

[image: End of first iteration]

Exactly at the **start of 2nd iteration** of loop, my private member `m_root` is:

[image: Start of second iteration]

I cannot figure out why content of private member `m_root` changes when ending 1st iteration and starting 2nd one.

Comment: Looks like your `Block` class fails to abide by the rule of 3/5/0, and thus can't be copied safely.

Comment: You are aware that you're looking at 2 different variables?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rafix07 deleted his comment, but his comment solved the problem:

Using reference:

```
for (Block &block : blocks)
```

Rather than copying:

```
for (Block block : blocks)
```

Comment: While this is true, you should look again closely at the comment from @Quentin.